# How to substitute switch statement with better solution - clean code hints

Tags: java, coding-style, switch-statement, refactoring

I created a code, which have to convert `ContentDataType` into `MIME` types. For example - `ContentDataType` is a simple `String` like `ImageJPEG` and now I use `MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE` to convert it into `image/jpeg`. But I use switch to do this. This is a code:

```
 public static String createContentType(ContentDataType contentDataType) {
        String contentType;

        switch (contentDataType) {          
            case IMAGE_JPG:
                contentType = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE;
                break;
            //next media types
        }
    return contentType;
 }
```

What is a better and elegant way to do this? I do not want to use `if`, but maybe some polymorphism? Can you give me any hints?

Comment: maybe create a Map

Comment: Something that has more code but might provide for a more flexible/dynamic solution would be to start with an `interface` which could take a `ContentDataType ` and return a `String`, then you'd create a registry, which would map the `interface` via `ContentDataType`, so you would simply pass the `ContentDataType` to the registry and would pass back a `String` or `null` based on the availability of a registered converter ... as a an idea

Comment: but map needs to be filled up with values. So I will need to do something like `put(ContentDataType, MediaType.Extenstion)`. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ready to use just one `if/else`You can do something like this :

```
private static Hashtable<String, String> types = new Hashtable<>();

static{
    types.put(IMAGE_JPG, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    types.put(IMAGE_PNG, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
    types.put(IMAGE_XXX, MediaType.IMAGE_XXX_VALUE);
}

public static String createContentType(ContentDataType contentDataType) {
    if types.containsKey(contentDataType) 
        return types.get(contentDataType);
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("contentDataType not supported");
    }
}
```

This allows you to add new supported types into the Hashtable whitout having to deal with a long sequence of `if/else if/else`.

Comment: 1) don't use `HashTable` use `HashMap`, unless you really require the synchronization; 2) get and check for null, rather than using containsKey and get (it's cheaper just to do one lookup, and the former can be atomic, the latter can't be, directly)

Comment: Also, it would be useful to print the offending `contentDataType` in the exception message.

Comment: This is the best choice to do this, I hope. Thank you for your answer. I only changed `Hashtable` into `HashMap`

Answer (score 1):

This type of operation should be used Enum.

If you have all the known possible options for your ContentDataType, then create a enum for the same.

Then you can store string as well as MIME type. like below,

```
enum ContentDataType{
    IMAGE_JPG("ImageJPG", "image/jpg"),
    IMAGE_GIF("ImageGIF", "image/gif");
    String contentType;
    String mimeType;
    ContentDataType(String contentType, String mimeType){
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }
}
```

Or you can use MimeType object as well as below

```
import com.google.common.net.MediaType;
enum ContentDataType{
    IMAGE_JPG("ImageJPG", MediaType.JPEG),
    IMAGE_GIF("ImageGIF", MediaType.GIF);
    public String contentType;
    public MediaType mimeType;
    ContentDataType(String contentType, MediaType mimeType){
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }
}
```